# PHP Remove multiple occurrences of multiline pattern with exclusion

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

[SOLVED] I need to achieve removing regexp pattern that match multiline strong distributed on various locations in content, but to exclude parts between first start keyword START_KEY_ONE and last ending keyword END_KEY_ONE.

In general, here is example of code:

```
$content = <<<EOS
Line 1
Line 2
/* START_KEY_ONE */
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
/* END_KEY_ONE */
Line 6
Line 7
/* START_KEY_TWO */
Line 8
/* END_KEY_TWO */
Line 9
Line 10
/* START_KEY_ONE */
Line 11
Line 12
/* END_KEY_ONE */
Line 13
/* START_KEY_TWO */
Line 14
/* END_KEY_TWO */
Line 15
EOS;

// $needle = '#/\* START_KEY_ONE.*END_KEY_ONE \*/\R#s'; // non working pattern
$needle = '#/\* START_KEY_ONE.*?END_KEY_ONE \*/\R#s'; // working pattern
echo preg_replace($needle,'',$content);
```

Instead of this (working pattern):

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 6
Line 7
/* START_KEY_TWO */
Line 8
/* END_KEY_TWO */
Line 9
Line 10
Line 13
/* START_KEY_TWO */
Line 14
/* END_KEY_TWO */
Line 15
```

I'm was getting this (non working pattern):

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 13
/* START_KEY_TWO */
Line 14
/* END_KEY_TWO */
Line 15
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this pattern:

```
~^\Q/* START_KEY_ONE */\E\R(?>.*\R)*?\Q/* END_KEY_ONE */\E\R?~m
```

The main interest is that the cost of the lazy quantifier is reduced since it occurs only once per line instead of once per character. An other advantage is the m modifier and the `^` anchor *(the pattern is only tested at the begining of a line, not for each character)*.The use of `\Q...\E` avoids to escape special characters and makes the pattern more readable.

Answer (score 1):

```
\/\*\s*START_KEY_ONE.*?END_KEY_ONE \*\/
```

Try this.See demo.Replace with `empty string`

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/jI8lV7/4

```
$re = "/\\/\\*\\s*START_KEY_ONE.*?END_KEY_ONE \\*\\//s";
$str = "Line 1\nLine 2\n/* START_KEY_ONE */\nLine 3\nLine 4\nLine 5\n/* END_KEY_ONE */\nLine 6\nLine 7\n/* START_KEY_TWO */\nLine 8\n/* END_KEY_TWO */\nLine 9\nLine 10\n/* START_KEY_ONE */\nLine 11\nLine 12\n/* END_KEY_ONE */\nLine 13\n/* START_KEY_TWO */\nLine 14\n/* END_KEY_TWO */\nLine 15";
$subst = "";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: Thank you! You spot missing detail (question mark in the middle of pattern).

Solved problem (empty string \s and escaping slash had no effect to my original pattern).

Comment: Yeah, because missing newline. That is why in my original pattern I use \R (instead \n because I don't know should file be edited on Windows, Max or Linux, so \n does not work in all cases).

Answer (score 1):

Change your regex like below and then replace the match with empty string. Don't forget to add `s` DOTALL modifier to your regex.

```
'~/\*\h+START_KEY_ONE\h+\*/.*?END_KEY_ONE\h+\*/\n~s'
```

You must need to add `\n` at the last , so that you won't get a blank line in output.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dI1cP2/6)

**Code:**

```
$content = <<<EOS
Line 1
Line 2
/* START_KEY_ONE */
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
/* END_KEY_ONE */
Line 6
Line 7
/* START_KEY_TWO */
Line 8
/* END_KEY_TWO */
Line 9
Line 10
/* START_KEY_ONE */
Line 11
Line 12
/* END_KEY_ONE */
Line 13
/* START_KEY_TWO */
Line 14
/* END_KEY_TWO */
Line 15
EOS;
$needle = '~/\*\h+START_KEY_ONE\h+\*/.*?END_KEY_ONE\h+\*/\n~s';
echo preg_replace($needle,'',$content);
```

**Output:**

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 6
Line 7
/* START_KEY_TWO */
Line 8
/* END_KEY_TWO */
Line 9
Line 10
Line 13
/* START_KEY_TWO */
Line 14
/* END_KEY_TWO */
Line 15
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dI1cP2/6)